# How to get user or page likes with Facebook SDK v5?

Tags: php, facebook

Hi my facebook app version is 2.7.I want to get user likes or page likes with Facebook SDK v5. I've get likes with user access token. But user access token expire after 1 day later. My php get request :

```
$request = new FacebookRequest
(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/',
  array(
    'fields' => 'email,name,gender,birthday,likes'
  )
);
```

I get user's email,name,gender,birthdate but I can't get user likes. How can I get user likes or page likes ?

Comment: Convert your access_token in long lived token;

Answer (score 1):

You need to authorize with the `user_likes` permission to get the likes. Keep in mind that you can only get the Pages a user likes, there is no way to get other likes (post likes, website likes, ...).

Make sure the Token includes the permission: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Btw, you can extend a User Token to be valid for 60 days:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Can i get pages user likes with app id an secret ?

Comment: of course not, you need to authorize the user and use a user token. app id and app secret are only an app token without any relation to any user.

Comment: Ok can i get user access token automatically after user logged in ?

Comment: yes, you get it after user login. just read through the links i posted, and this one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ - keep in mind that you don´t need to handle the user token on your own while using one of the SDKs (php sdk, js sdk, ...).

Comment: I tried $longLivedSession = $session->getLongLivedSession();
$access_token=$longLivedSession->getToken(); from http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/ . But I didnt get likes with this user access token .

Comment: so, did you authorize with the user_likes permission as i mentioned in my answer? did you debug the token and does it include the permission? > https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: well, there is your answer ;)

Comment: well can i get page likes with page tooken?

Comment: you mean, the pages a user likes, or the pages a page likes? should be easy to test ;)

Comment: who likes my page :)

Comment: you mean the fans? that is not possible at all. what would you do with the list anyway?

Comment: If user like my fan page , user can access my wifi

Comment: i believe that works in a different way, i believe you can make them check in at your place with some setting: https://www.facebook.com/business/facebook-wifi - btw, you need to read the platform policy: "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions" - forcing people to like your page is not allowed.